# Jenkins: extract version and artifactid from maven for docker image name/tag

Tags: spring-boot, docker, maven, jenkins

I am using spring boot maven plugin to generate my docker images.
I defined the image name to be dynamic in my pom file. Format: `my-registry.com/prefix/${project.artifactId}:${project.version}`

How can i get the dynamic name of the image generated? I need it for further build steps (deployment)

My build pipeline looks like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'maven:3-jdk-11' 
            args '-v /root/.m2:/root/.m2' 
        }
    }

    stages {
        stage('Clone sources') {
            steps {
                git branch: 'master',
                    credentialsId: 'xxxxx',
                    url: 'xxxxxx'
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh "mvn -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true clean install"
            }

            post {
                success {
                    junit '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
                    archiveArtifacts 'myproject-server/target/*.jar'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Build and Push Docker Image') {
            steps {
                withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'xxxxx', passwordVariable: 'NEXUS_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'NEXUS_USER')]) {
                    sh "mvn -pl myproject-server -DskipTests=true spring-boot:build-image -DDOCKER_REGISTRY=xxxx -DDOCKER_REGISTRY_USER=$NEXUS_USER -DDOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD=$NEXUS_PASSWORD"
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy to DEV') {
            steps {
                sshagent(credentials : ['xxxx']) {
                    sh 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@server DOCKER RUN LOGIC HERE WITH CORRECT IMAGE NAME'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Jenkins Pipeline Utility Steps plugin (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/) to read the POM file and extract the value.

```
pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'
pom.version
```

But as stated in their docs

> Avoid using this step and writeMavenPom. It is better to use the sh step to run mvn goals. For example

You could use this command instead:

```
def version = sh script: 'mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout', returnStdout: true
```